# I cannot see what branch I am on GIT

Tags: git

I have created a GIT branch.

I was seeing the branch (eg C:\Branch (myBranch)) After creating new branch I am not seeing what branch I am on anymore.

```
git branch new_branch
```

I see only C:\branch.

I want to see `c:\branch (new_branch)`

When I do
git status it shows "on new_branch"

Thank you in advance

Comment: What console are you using? Git bash? Command prompt? Power shell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all when you do a `git branch` you are not switching to the new branch.

```
git checkout -b <branch_name>
```

will create and switch you to your new branch.

On windows if you are using the command line (cmd) you have to set it manually.
[Here] is an example on how to do it.

Much better way is to use the `git bash`. Simply right click on your folder and use the `git Bash here` from the menu.

The git bash has a build in prompt to show you the branch name.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Oh I see.  That is helpful.  I am using Cmdr.  Which use to show me what branch I am on but not anymore.  That is what I wanted to know why? Now Git bash looks like a good idea.